# \unidirectionalAssociation usage problem in pgf-umlcd?

Tags: pgf-umlcd

I use [pgf-umlcd manual](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-umlcd/pgf-umlcd-manual.pdf) as manual to create uml diagrum. But, when I use `\unidirectionalAssociation` command there occurs a problem.
My code here -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=8in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{class}{VocabularyObserver}{-3, -6} 
    \attribute{\# vocabulary : Vocabulary}
    \operation{\# update(word : String) : void}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 12 cm]{Vocabulary}{-3,-10}
    \attribute{- vocabularyObservers : List<VocabularyObserver>}
    \attribute{+ MAXWORD : int}
    \attribute{+ wordCounter : int}
    \attribute{+ wordList : String[]}
    \operation{+ addWord() : Boolean}
    \operation{+ addObservers(vocabularyObserver : VocabularyObserver) : void}
    \operation{- notifyAllObservers(word : String) : void}
  \end{class}
\unidirectionalAssociation{uses}{VocabularyObserver}{0..*}{Vocabulary}
 \end{tikzpicture}   
 \end{document}
```

compilation error is here -

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

! Package pgf Error: No shape named uses is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21 ...ses}{VocabularyObserver}{0..*}{Vocabulary}

?
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be at least within `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @TeXnician I put it within `tikzpicture`. Now the error is `*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

! Package pgf Error: No shape named uses is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21 ...ses}{VocabularyObserver}{0..*}{Vocabulary}
                                                  
?`

Comment: The first argument has to be the first class, the last argument the second class and in between the description and the relation. You mixed it up.

Comment: @TeXnician this works, but the description shown on the association line. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "but the description shown on the association line"?

Comment: @TeXnician see this http://img.ctrlv.in/img/17/08/31/59a7a13f3cc1d.png image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64871/discussion-between-banda-muhammad-al-helal-and-texnician).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TeXnician said, the reason you're getting the error is that your arguments to `\unidirectionalAssociation` is in the wrong order. You should have

```
\unidirectionalAssociation{<name of first class>}{<text above>}{<text below>}{<name of second class>}
```

but what you have is

```
\unidirectionalAssociation{<text above>}{<name of first class>}{<text below>}{<name of second class>}
```

The reason you're getting the text on top of the line is the definition of `\unidirectionalAssociation`, which seems to be designed with only horizontal lines in mind, as the two nodes are placed `above` and `below`, respectively.

A more general approach would be

```
\renewcommand{\unidirectionalAssociation}[4]{
  \draw [umlcd style, ->] (#1) -- (#4)
    node[near end, auto]{#2}
    node[near end, auto,swap]{#3};
}
```

where `above` has been replaced with `auto`, and `below` with `auto,swap`. With this definition it will work for lines with other orientations as well, as seen from the example below. (The two `demo` classes are there purely to demonstrate this.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=8in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\unidirectionalAssociation}[4]{
  \draw [umlcd style, ->] (#1) -- (#4)
    node[near end, auto]{#2}
    node[near end, auto,swap]{#3};
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{class}{demo}{-10, -6} 
    \attribute{foo}
    \operation{bar}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{demo2}{-12, -10} 
    \attribute{foo2}
    \operation{bar2}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}{VocabularyObserver}{-3, -6} 
    \attribute{\# vocabulary : Vocabulary}
    \operation{\# update(word : String) : void}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 12 cm]{Vocabulary}{-3,-10}
    \attribute{- vocabularyObservers : List<VocabularyObserver>}
    \attribute{+ MAXWORD : int}
    \attribute{+ wordCounter : int}
    \attribute{+ wordList : String[]}
    \operation{+ addWord() : Boolean}
    \operation{+ addObservers(vocabularyObserver : VocabularyObserver) : void}
    \operation{- notifyAllObservers(word : String) : void}
  \end{class}
\unidirectionalAssociation{VocabularyObserver}{uses}{0..*}{Vocabulary}

\unidirectionalAssociation{demo}{bar}{baz}{VocabularyObserver}
\unidirectionalAssociation{demo2}{here}{there}{VocabularyObserver}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: I intent to edit the "pgf-umlcd.sty" file with this style so that for all uml it acts same. but I don't understand why first position is `auto` and second is both `auto` and `swap`.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal `auto` places the node on the left side of the line (if you look from the start point to the end point), `auto,swap` places it on the right side. Without `swap` the two nodes would be placed in the same place.

Comment: From where you know the option `auto` and `swap`?  I was motivated to change "pgf-umlcd.sty" by your [comment on another my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391474/how-to-draw-these-association-using-pgf-umlcd#comment972432_391476)

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal The TikZ manual ...

Comment: by your comment I learned a great things of LaTeX. thank you.

Comment: I edit my `pgf-umlcd.sty` file, it works well. thanks.

Comment: how to put level in middle from each node in pgf-umlcd? I do this `\unidirectionalAssociation{WindowManagerApplication}{$<<$instantiate$>>$}{}{WindowManager}`
 that result [this](https://imgur.com/a/hlkiw)

Comment: @alhelal You should be able to work that out given the info I've provided in some of your other questions I think. `\draw [umlcd style,->] (WindowManagerApplication) -- node[above]{instantiate} (WindowManager);` The `\unidirectionalAssociation` macro just isn't very flexible as it is defined, the position of the two nodes that hold the text you provide in the second and third argument is fixed at `near end`, and to modify that the macro has to be rewritten somehow.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. Can I shift the `<<instantiate>>` left so that it doesn't overlap `WindowManager`?

Comment: @alhelal 1) `\draw [umlcd style,->] (WindowManagerApplication) -- node[above]{<<instantiate>>} (WindowManager);`  puts it in the middle. 2) `\unidirectionalAssociation` doesn't put those labels in the middle of the line. If you want it to do that, you have to redefine it somehow. 3) You could possibly use an ugly hack like `\unidirectionalAssociation{WindowManagerApplication}{$<<$ins‌​tantiate$>>$ \hspace{1cm}\null}{}{Wind‌​owManager}`. 4) If you have a lot of these, making a new macro might be worthwhile.

Comment: Why does `\draw[umlcd style] (WindowManagerApplication.south) -- ++(DesignFactory.north)` give unexpected line?

Comment: @alhelal Because of the `++`, which indicates relative coordinates. Remove the `++`. (Probably, I haven’t tested.)

Comment: Isn't it relative coordinates? when  I will change the position of `DesignFactory` the line will be changed?

Comment: @alhelal Relative to the *previous* coordinate. If `a` is at (1,2) and `b` is at (3,1), when you do `\draw (a) -- ++(b);` the endpoint is at (4,3), not at (3,1).

Comment: why [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25834562/) results `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.` I tried long time but didn't find any error.

Comment: @alhelal Ask a new question, and include a code example.