# How to draw these association using pgf-umlcd?

Tags: pgf-umlcd

In [pgf-umlcd manual](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-umlcd/pgf-umlcd-manual.pdf) the composition and aggregation line are 2 side arrowed. How can I draw one side arrowed that looks like-

[image: association types]

These association are described in [wikipedia class diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Instance-level_relationships)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to redefine the `\aggregation` and `\composition` macros. Try adding

```
\renewcommand{\aggregation}[4]
{
\draw[umlcd style, -open diamond] (#1) -- (#4)
node[near end, above]{#2}
node[near end, below]{#3};
}

\renewcommand{\composition}[4]
{
\draw[umlcd style, fill=\umldrawcolor, -diamond] (#1) -- (#4)
node[near end, above]{#2}
node[near end, below]{#3};
}
```

to the preamble after loading `pgf-umlcd`. The default arrow tip specifications are `open diamond->` and `diamond->`, respectively, so a diamond at the start of the line and a standard arrow tip at the end. With the above modification you'll get just a diamond at the end. If you need the diamonds at the start, use `open diamond-` and `diamond-`

Comment: for curiosity, from where you learn the draw command so that you easily change the default behavior?

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Ehm, well. `\draw` is from TikZ, and that package I've learned mainly from its manual and questions/answers on this site. But the code I showed above is simply copied from `pgf-umlcd.sty`, and then I changed `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand`, in addition to the change of the arrow tip specification.