# What is meant by "! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?." when I use pgf-umlcd?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-umlcd

My code is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\renewcommand{\unidirectionalAssociation}[4]
{
  draw[umlcd style, ->] (#1) -- (#4)
  node[near end, auto]{#2}
  node[near end, auto,swap]{#3};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{abstractclass}[text width = 6cm]{FileStore}{0,0}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \operation{+ orderFile(file : File) : EditableFile} 
    \operation[0]{\# createFile(file : File) : EditableFile}
  \end{abstractclass}

  \begin{class}[text width = 6cm,anchor = west,xshift = 5cm]{ProgrammFileFactory}{FileStore.east}
    \inherit{FileStore}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \operation{+ orderFile(file : File) : EditableFile} 
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 11cm, yshift = -2cm]{EditableFile}{ProgrammFileFactory.south}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \attribute{+ languageBehavior : LanguageBehavior} 
    \operation{+ options : Options} 
    \operation{+ getCodeAreaFromTab(tb : Tab) : CodeArea} 
    \operation{+ saveFile(fileTabArrayList : ArrayList$<$FileTab$>$, option : Options)}
    \operation{+ printFile(node : Node)}
    \operation{+ toggleLineNumber(cd : CodeArea)}
    \operation{+ setLanguageBehavior(langBehavior : LanguageBehavior)}
    \operation{+ performRunCode(file : File)}
    \operation{+ performBuildCode(file : File)}
    \operation{+ performSetHighlightableText()}
    \operation{+ performSetAutocompletableText()}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 3.5cm,anchor=north east,yshift = -2cm, xshift=-6cm]{TextFile}{EditableFile.south west}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 3.5cm,anchor=north east,yshift = -2cm, xshift = -1.5cm]{CFile}{EditableFile.south west}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \attribute{-path : String}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width=3.5cm,anchor=north west,yshift = -2cm,xshift=-3cm]{CplusFile}{EditableFile.south}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width  = 3.5cm, anchor = north west, yshift = -2cm, xshift = -4cm]{JavaFile}{EditableFile.south east}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 3.5cm,yshift = -2cm,xshift = 1cm]{PythonFile}{EditableFile.south east}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 3.5cm, anchor = north west, yshift =-2cm,xshift = 5cm]{LaTeXFile}{EditableFile.south east}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}
  \unidirectionalAssociation{ProgrammFileFactory}{}{$<<$instantiate$>>$}{EditableFile}
  \node [above=3mm] at (current bounding box.north) {Factory Method Pattern}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I run this using `pdflatex` in terminal that results in

[image]

Comment: This is actually one of those cases where the error message is completely accurate: As Skillmon says you forgot a semicolon at the end of the last `\node` you added.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Note that if you get a message about a missing semicolon for the command on line X, you are probably missing the semicolon at the end of the _previous_ command - on line X-1.

Answer (score 3):

The general syntax of `TikZ` is to enter the stuff you want to be drawn in a format matching something like:

```
\command [ options ] ( location ) { stuff } ;
```

Where almost everything might not be needed. Just the `\command` (e.g. `\draw`) and the trailing `;` to limit the scope of the command, are important. You forgot that `;` in the last line  of your `tikzpicture` and therefore get this error. And you forgot a `\` at beginning of `draw`  in the `\unidirectionAssociation` renaming block.
Use `\draw[umlcd style, ->] (#1) -- (#4)` instead of `draw[umlcd style, ->] (#1) -- (#4)`

The following compiles:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\renewcommand{\unidirectionalAssociation}[4]
{
  \draw[umlcd style, ->] (#1) -- (#4)% <------
  node[near end, auto]{#2}
  node[near end, auto,swap]{#3};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{abstractclass}[text width = 6cm]{FileStore}{0,0}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \operation{+ orderFile(file : File) : EditableFile} 
    \operation[0]{\# createFile(file : File) : EditableFile}
  \end{abstractclass}

  \begin{class}[text width = 6cm,anchor = west,xshift = 5cm]{ProgrammFileFactory}{FileStore.east}
    \inherit{FileStore}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \operation{+ orderFile(file : File) : EditableFile} 
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 11cm, yshift = -2cm]{EditableFile}{ProgrammFileFactory.south}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \attribute{+ languageBehavior : LanguageBehavior} 
    \operation{+ options : Options} 
    \operation{+ getCodeAreaFromTab(tb : Tab) : CodeArea} 
    \operation{+ saveFile(fileTabArrayList : ArrayList$<$FileTab$>$, option : Options)}
    \operation{+ printFile(node : Node)}
    \operation{+ toggleLineNumber(cd : CodeArea)}
    \operation{+ setLanguageBehavior(langBehavior : LanguageBehavior)}
    \operation{+ performRunCode(file : File)}
    \operation{+ performBuildCode(file : File)}
    \operation{+ performSetHighlightableText()}
    \operation{+ performSetAutocompletableText()}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 3.5cm,anchor=north east,yshift = -2cm, xshift=-6cm]{TextFile}{EditableFile.south west}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 3.5cm,anchor=north east,yshift = -2cm, xshift = -1.5cm]{CFile}{EditableFile.south west}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
    \attribute{-path : String}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width=3.5cm,anchor=north west,yshift = -2cm,xshift=-3cm]{CplusFile}{EditableFile.south}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width  = 3.5cm, anchor = north west, yshift = -2cm, xshift = -4cm]{JavaFile}{EditableFile.south east}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 3.5cm,yshift = -2cm,xshift = 1cm]{PythonFile}{EditableFile.south east}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}

  \begin{class}[text width = 3.5cm, anchor = north west, yshift =-2cm,xshift = 5cm]{LaTeXFile}{EditableFile.south east}
    \inherit{EditableFile}
    \attribute{$\sim$ com.alhelal.textpad}
  \end{class}
  \unidirectionalAssociation{ProgrammFileFactory}{}{$<<$instantiate$>>$}{EditableFile}
  \node [above=3mm] at (current bounding box.north) {Factory Method Pattern};% <-------
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I marked the lines I changed with `% <-------`.

**EDIT:** I've updated the above code to include the correct redefinition of `\unidirectionalAssociation` thanks to the clarifications provided by @TorbjørnT.

[image]

Comment: I put `\` which included in my question. Your solution doesn't results any error message, but I don't get the proper output.  association not shown. see [this](https://pasteboard.co/GQZI73C.png) and why no.2 and no.4 inherited line arrow is less deep. see [tihs](https://pasteboard.co/GQZIMUi.png)

Comment: @alhelal did you apply the proposed changes (the last code block in my answer) to `\unidirectionalAssociation`? With this the two described issues are solved.

Comment: @alhelal why do you change the definition of `\unidirectionalAssociation` in the first place?

Comment: The macro redefinition was suggested by me (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389248/) because the original one doesn't work for vertical lines. And your last version is the one I suggested, somehow the OP lost a ```\``` along the way. Edit: I'd suggest changing the one in the complete example to the same, instead of adding those semicolons.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks for the clarification, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Skillmon I spend long time to find out the missing `\`, that makes my output ambiguous, so I edit your answer with this information.